# searching a string in array by partial of it

Tags: javascript, node.js, pawn, altv

I wanna find a string inside an array by some part of its name(at least more than 3characters), Like:
Buffalo is an index of array and I want to search buf or buff, buffa, buffal or even the hole word(buffalo) and it return Buffalo.
**No matter if its case-sensitive or NOT**

here is my array:

```
const carsName =
      [
          "Landstalker",
          "Bravura",
          "Buffalo",
          "Linerunner",
          "Perrenial",
          "Sentinel",
          "Dumper",
          "Firetruck",
          "Trashmaster",
          "Stretch",
          "Manana",
          "Infernus"
      ]
```

I wrote it in PAWN once and I'm gonna write it in JS (for my Alt V server) but I'm stuck at this point, is it possible to do?

and at the end, sorry for my English

Comment: The tags are not just-for-fun. Please only add relevant tags.

Comment: _"I'm gonna write it in JS"_ - So this is about JavaScript? Then the first step would be to use an actual array instead of a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Case insensitive partial match:

```js
const carsName = [
  "Landstalker",
  "Bravura",
  "Buffalo",
  "Linerunner",
  "Perrenial",
  "Sentinel",
  "Dumper",
  "Firetruck",
  "Trashmaster",
  "Stretch",
  "Manana",
  "Infernus",
];

const partial = 'buf';

const foundName = carsName.find(
  name => name.toLowerCase().includes(partial.toLowerCase())
);

console.log(foundName);
```

Comment: Thank u but its  the answer

Comment: @MohammadJavadBehravan Sorry, not sure if I understand your comment.

Comment: Don't be, I mean if user enter a string (more than 3char), search in cars array and find the car that user is looking for
Hope I could explained it well